# In tensorflow, can you define your own collection name?

Tags: collections, tensorflow

I searched all resources in tensorflow's API documents and can't find any indication.
It seems when using get_variable(), I can put a specific name for collections term like:

```
x=tf.get_variable('x',[2,2],collections='my_scope')
```

but get only empty list when doing:

```
tf.get_collection('my_scope')
```

Answer (score 6):

collection**S** needs a `list` of collection name.

```
>>x = tf.get_variable('x',[2,2], collections=['my_scope'])
>>tf.get_collection('my_scope')

[<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable at 0x10d8e1590>]
```

watch out that if you use it some other operations can have side effects.
like `tf.all_variables()` will not work and thus `tf.initialize_all_variables()` also will not see your variable. One way to fix it is to specify the default collection too.

```
>>x = tf.get_variable('x',[2,2], collections=['my_scope', tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES])
```

but things starts to get tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use `tf.get_collection` to create a new collection:

```
tf.get_collection('my_collection')
var = tf.get_variable('var', [2, 2], initializer=tf.constant_initializer())
tf.add_to_collection('my_collection', var)
```